# Bootstrap grid custom layout

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have been learning this design

[image]

```
<section>
    <div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                <img src="image.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            </div>        
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                <img src="image.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                <img src="image.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                <img src="image.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    </div>
</section>
```

I am getting the below design

[image]

Could you please help me on this design and let me know where am i going wrong?

Thank you

Comment: I know you are using bootstrap but have you tried just using css, display flex and grid? Do you have any interest in it?

Comment: yes i do and in _grid.scss - @media (min-width: 992px)
.col-lg-6 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
}

Comment: I mean not using bootstrap at all for this. This is fairly "easy" to do. What are your requirments for html, like does it have to follow a structure? What does it look like in mobile, is there a relation between the pictures with different grids you have posted?

Comment: I am already using bootstrap 4 for in this design, only this particular has alignment issues. The first image is the requirement of the design, which looks exactly same

Answer (score 1):

```
<section>
   <div class="container">
       <div class="row">               
           <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
               <img src="image.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">       
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                <img src="image.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                        <img src="image.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                        <img src="image.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

[image]